# General workflow with Python and User Modules

Tags: python, workflow, python-module

I am working on some Python code that has several run scripts or demo scripts. Each of these calls from a module called 'util'. Presently the 'demo' directory and the 'util' directory are on the same level.

I understand that to access util functions inside demo I need to append to my path and that all works fine. It's just a little annoying that I need to do that for every script in demo. Is there any way to globally apply that path to all scripts in util?

For example, my structure looks like:

```
py
| demo
|  | demo1.py
|  | demo2.py
| util
|  | __init__.py
|  | util_fn1.py
|  | util_fn2.py
```

At the top of each demo function, I have

```py
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
```

which enables me to say things like:

```py
from util.util_fn1 import foo
```

I guess my question is whether or not there's a way to do this without having to put that at the top of every demo file.

Also, I run things from the top-level 'py' directory.

Comment: You can do this by editing your environment variables, particularly by adding the directory containing these files to the PYTHONPATH variable.

Comment: I did consider this, but this is just a single project repository that I want to be able to jump in and out of using virtual environments. Is there an easy way to do this automatically when activating the virtual environment?